# how to fetch aws secret to use as mysql password to run a docker container and pass the credential

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-secrets-manager, user-data

i am trying to achieve a scenario where i would like to run a docker container using user-data in aws whenever the instance is stopped and start. I am not able to set the environment variable
using "echo" or export e.g

```
      export MYSQL_HOST=<mysqlsql host url> or echo export MYSQL_HOST=<mysql host url>
```

i even tried to redirect it to /etc/profile.d as suggest in other posts but i get permission denied.

i have also tried to get the secret from aws-cli and store it in a variable and later use this variable when docker command runs but this also does not work, however when i do the same logic on ec2 instance itself it works. please suggest how to accomplish this. This is what i have done so far

```
       Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
       MIME-Version: 1.0

       --//
       Content-Type: text/cloud-config; charset="us-ascii"
       MIME-Version: 1.0
       Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
       Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="cloud-config.txt"

       #cloud-config
       cloud_final_modules:
       - [scripts-user, always]

       --//
       Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"
       MIME-Version: 1.0
       Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
       Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="userdata.txt"
       #!/bin/bash
       sudo yum install docker -y
       sudo service docker start

      sudo yum install -y https://s3.amazonaws.com/ec2-downloads- 
      windows/SSMAgent/latest/linux_arm64/amazon-ssm-agent.rpm
      sudo systemctl enable amazon-ssm-agent
      sudo systemctl start amazon-ssm-agent
      export secret=`aws secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id <secret id> --region eu- 
      west-2|grep SecretString|awk -F\" '{print $4}'`
      sudo docker pull <image url from ecr>
      sudo docker run -d --restart always -p 8000:80 -e **MYSQL_PASSWORD=$secret** <image id>

      --//
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put some debugging statements into your script, to see what is set where. But a few comments that may help you solve the problem:

- I don't see that you're setting the value of `MYSQL_HOST`; you're just retrieving (and exporting) the secret value.
- `sudo` doesn't pass environment variables to the subshell unless you use `--preserve-env`
- if you have an variable set in your environment, then you just need to use `-e VARNAME` to pass it to Docker
- Don't put spaces in arguments (as you do here with `MYSQL_HOST`). That tells the shell that the variable should be assigned an empty string.
- I'm not sure whether those asterisks in `**MYSQL_HOST= $MYSQL_HOST**` are from you highlighting text for the question, or are actually in your secript. In either case, don't do it; we want to see what you're *actually* running.

Comment: hi thanks for your reply, i have now edited the question and used exactly what i am using right now, here i only put the mysql_password but i also have other variable to use e.h host, username, but if i can achieve one i will do the other same way. Main issue is i would like to query aws secrets manager, store the value in a variable and then use it in docker run command.

Comment: @srk786 - so you're passing `**MYSQL_PASSWORD=$secret**`? that isn't going to work.

Comment: Also, what errors are you getting? What, _exactly_ is happening? And are you sure that the secret value is correct? Again, you need to add some debug logging to your script.